# File Handling in C programming

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I am trying to learn C. :) however I am getting this error which I do not understand . Can somebody please explain this to me. I am not able to understand what is causing this issue.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
    FILE *fp, *ft;
    char ch;
    fp=fopen("D:\Documents\sample.txt","w");
    if (fp ==NULL) 
    {
        puts("cannot open file");
        exit();
    }

    ft=fopen("D:\Documents\sample - Copy.txt","w");
     if (ft ==NULL) 
    {
        puts("cannot open file");
        exit();
    }

    while(1)
    {
        ch=fgetc(fp);
        if (ch== EOF)
            break;
        else
            fputc(ch,ft);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ft);
}
```

Error message I am getting :-

```
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c: In function 'main':
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:8:11: warning: unknown escape sequenc
e: '\D' [enabled by default]
  fp=fopen("D:\Documents\sample.txt","w");
           ^
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:8:11: warning: unknown escape sequenc
e: '\s' [enabled by default]
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:12:6: warning: incompatible implicit
declaration of built-in function 'exit' [enabled by default]
      exit();
      ^
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:12:6: error: too few arguments to fun
ction 'exit'
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:15:11: warning: unknown escape sequen
ce: '\D' [enabled by default]
  ft=fopen("D:\Documents\sample - Copy.txt","w");
           ^
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:15:11: warning: unknown escape sequen
ce: '\s' [enabled by default]
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:19:6: warning: incompatible implicit
declaration of built-in function 'exit' [enabled by default]
      exit();
      ^
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:19:6: error: too few arguments to fun
ction 'exit'

C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop>gcc C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c -o Fi
leHandling
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c: In function 'main':
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:8:11: warning: unknown escape sequenc
e: '\D' [enabled by default]
  fp=fopen("D:/\Documents/\sample.txt","w");
           ^
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:8:11: warning: unknown escape sequenc
e: '\s' [enabled by default]
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:12:6: warning: incompatible implicit
declaration of built-in function 'exit' [enabled by default]
      exit();
      ^
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:12:6: error: too few arguments to fun
ction 'exit'
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:15:11: warning: unknown escape sequen
ce: '\D' [enabled by default]
  ft=fopen("D:/\Documents/\sample - Copy.txt","w");
           ^
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:15:11: warning: unknown escape sequen
ce: '\s' [enabled by default]
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:19:6: warning: incompatible implicit
declaration of built-in function 'exit' [enabled by default]
      exit();
      ^
C:\Users\LoneRanger\Desktop\FileHandling.c:19:6: error: too few arguments to fun
ction 'exit'
```

Comment: C is not C++ or Objective-C.

Comment: It says "error: too few arguments to function 'exit'". Change exit() to exit(1) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` is escape symbol in C, you should use `\\` in your strings, like:

```
fp=fopen("D:\\Documents\\sample.txt","w");
```

Answer (score 2):

`exit()` is in `stdlib.h` and you don't include this header so there is a error.

Also `return` is a better option than `exit` here

Answer (score 1):

In C, C++, C#, and a bunch of other languages, you can make strings with special characters, such as adding a new line (`'\n'`), a tab (`'\t'`) and many others.

The convention is to 'escape' them, that is, use a backslash `\` and one or more characters to symbolize the character you want. This means that `\` is special in a string and you need to use it with care.

In your case, when you want to use a real `\` to separate directories, you need to escape it as `\\`